# Find pixel indices within a shape: Opencv and Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

Suppose I have a mask of a hollow, curved (and not necessarily convex) shape that I've received from my pre-processing steps:

[image: Hollow circle mask]

I now want to try and select all pixels that occur *inside* that shape and add them to the mask, as so:

[image: Filled circle mask]

How can I do this in Python?

---

Code for generating the examples:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters for creating the circle
COLOR_BLUE = (255, 0, 0)
IMAGE_SHAPE = (256, 256, 3)
CIRCLE_CENTER = tuple(np.array(IMAGE_SHAPE) // 2)[:-1]
CIRCLE_RADIUS = 30
LINE_THICKNESS = 5 # Change to -1 for example of filled circle

# Draw on a circle
img = np.zeros(IMAGE_SHAPE, dtype=np.uint8)
img_circle = cv2.circle(img, CIRCLE_CENTER, CIRCLE_RADIUS, COLOR_BLUE, LINE_THICKNESS)
circle_mask = img_circle[:, :, 0]

# Show the image
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(circle_mask)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `floodFill` to fill the outside of the circle. Then use `np.where` to find the pixels within the circle

```
cv2.floodFill(circle_mask, None, (0, 0), 1)
np.where(circle_mask == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other methods:

**Method #1:** [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) + [`cv2.drawContours`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#how-to-draw-the-contours)

Find contours then fill in the contour

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(circle_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(circle_mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
```

**Method #2:** [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)
 + [`cv2.fillPoly`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly)

Again find contours then fill in using a different filling function

```
cv2.fillPoly(circle_mask, cnts, (255,255,255))
```

[image]

Full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Parameters for creating the circle
COLOR_BLUE = (255, 0, 0)
IMAGE_SHAPE = (256, 256, 3)
CIRCLE_CENTER = tuple(np.array(IMAGE_SHAPE) // 2)[:-1]
CIRCLE_RADIUS = 30
LINE_THICKNESS = 5 # Change to -1 for example of filled circle

# Draw on a circle
img = np.zeros(IMAGE_SHAPE, dtype=np.uint8)
img_circle = cv2.circle(img, CIRCLE_CENTER, CIRCLE_RADIUS, COLOR_BLUE, LINE_THICKNESS)
circle_mask = img_circle[:, :, 0].astype(np.uint8)

# Method #1
cnts = cv2.findContours(circle_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(circle_mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Method #2
# cv2.fillPoly(circle_mask, cnts, (255,255,255))

# Show the image
cv2.imshow('circle_mask', circle_mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that `cv2.findContours` performed quite badly on very curvy shapes that curled back in on themselves (i.e. strongly concave). I didn't include any of those examples in the original post as I didn't want to include a whole lot of clunky code for generating examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes).